# If $f$ preserves identity and inverses, is it necessarily a group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, inverse, group-homomorphism

It is a well-known fact that for any group homomorphism $f\colon (G,*)\to (H,\circ)$ we have
\begin{gather*}
f(1_G)=1_H\\
f(x^{-1})=f(x)^{-1}
\end{gather*}

What about the converse?

---

**Question.** If $f$ is a function which preserves the identity and the inverses, is it necessarily a group homomorphism? Is it true if we additionally assume that $f$ is bijection? Is it true if $(G,*)=(H,\circ)$ (i.e., for functions - or bijective functions - $(G,*) \to (G,*))$?

Or maybe the question is better formulated **like this:** What are some nice/natural counterexamples to the above claims?

---

There should be some easy-to-find counterexamples. For example, if we take a group $G$ such that each element is self-inverse, i.e., $x*x=e$ for each $x\in G$, then the condition about inverses is trivially true; it just says $f(x)=f(x)$. So we are left with the maps preserving the identity. Such maps (even bijections) are unlikely to be always homomorphisms.

Comment: Let $X_G$ be a subset of $G\setminus\{1\}$ such that if $x\in X_G$ and $x$ has order at least $3$ then $x^{-1}$ does not lie in $X_G$. Similarly for $X_H$. Any function between $X_G$ and $X_H$ extends to a map of your form.

Comment: Consider $f:  g\mapsto g^{-1}$.  That's not a homomorphism unless the group is abelian.  It is, of course, a bijection.

Comment: The smallest example is a group of order $5$. Here, the map $x\to x$, $x^4\to x^4$, $x^2\leftrightarrow x^3$ is an example.

Comment: Naturally not, it preserves the nullary and unary operations, but not necessarily the binary one.

Answer (score 2):

Different group structures on the same set could have the same identity (nullary) and inversion (unary) operations. For example, one could define $g \circ h$ to be $h*g$ to get the so-called opposite group, and $\circ$ is not the same as $*$ unless $(G,*)$ is abelian. Nonetheless, the identity in $(G,\circ)$ is the same as the one in $(G,*)$, and so is inversion. This means that the identity map $(G,*) \to (G,\circ)$ preserves the identity and inversion but is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will just add that this is closely related to the map $g\to g^{-1}$ considered as a map $(G,*)\to(G,*)$. This maps gives an isomorphism between $G$ and the [opposite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group) $G^{op}$. And it is precisely the map [from lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301280/if-f-preserves-identity-and-inverses-is-it-necessarily-a-group-homomorphism/4301396#comment8958166_4301280).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is a nonabelian Lie group with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Its exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ (viewing $\mathfrak{g}$ as a Lie group under addition) is not a homomorphism, but it intertwines with inversion. Indeed, not only does it intertwine with inversion, it intertwines with all powers: $\exp(nX)=\exp(X)^n$. Even beyond this, its restriction to any 1D subspace *is* a homomorphism!

If you're unfamiliar with Lie theory, take $\exp:(M_2(\mathbb{R}),+)\to\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}$, where $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of $2\times2$ real matrices under addition, $\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}$ is the group of invertible $2\times2$ real matrices under matrix multiplication, and the exponential function is defined by the usual power series, only applied to matrices instead of scalars (it always converges).